# Frequent Allocation/Deallocation of an Object - Objective -C

Tags: objective-c, object, memory-management, allocation, lazy-initialization

I'm using "Requests Buffer" class as a @property of my main Model class. There is a lazy instantiation for the buffer and when there are no items to process in the buffer model sets it to nil. I'm wondering if there is a reasonable frequency for allocation and deallocation of the complex buffer object? And when may be it make sense just to keep it allocated in the instance variable during all life-cycle of the model? May be someone can explain mechanics behind allocation, is it done at a cost of CPU? Please advise.
There are about 5-10 allocations/deallocations per second.

Answer (score 2):

Did you measure it?   Is there a user apparent performance issue on the least capable piece of hardware that you are supporting?   Did you test it in both low-bandwidth/high-latency vs. high-bandwidth/low-latency situations?

If there is no apparent issue to the user across bandwidth configurations with the lowest powered and highest powered configurations, then further pursuit is nothing more than [a very valuable] educational exercise.

If there is an issue, there is no way to know where the performance bottleneck is until *you measure it*.   Can't optimize what you don't know to be slow!

The Allocations Instrument and CPU profiler Instrument are both excellent tools for quantifying performance.

---

Reasonably sized allocations are relatively cheap, though they do require a synchronization operation (or a few) across threads.   Consumption of *new* memory is expensive, but fluttering on a working set with lots of allocs/deallocs is typically pretty fast.   In any system with lots of alloc/dealloc traffic, there will be fragmentation and that will be costly over time.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these rules:

- write clean and well structured code
- get it to work
- **if** it doesn't perform well, profile it and identify the bottlenecks

Only then look at optimization.

5-10 allocations/deallocations per second will under normal circumstances not be noticeable, unless there is some complex and slow initialization or synchronization code involved..